# Error installing pip pyicu

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, musicbrainz

I have been trying to install musicbrainz server on my mac and there is a step where I have to install pip pyicu. I keep getting this error:

```
Collecting pyicu
Downloading PyICU-1.9.5.tar.gz (181kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 184kB 515kB/s 
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/tmp/pip-build-E50o2C/pyicu/setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    ICU_VERSION = subprocess.check_output(('icu-config', '--version')).strip()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-E50o2C/pyicu/
```

I have tried downloading ez_setup.py and doing python ez_setup.py. I have upgraded the setuptools and downloaded those separately as well. I am not sure what else there is to try. Please help!

Comment: The musicbrainz server is written in Perl, which part of it makes you try installing pyicu?

Comment: I keep getting this error : fatal error: 'unicode/utypes.h' file not found after trying the make command. After that I try pip install polyglot, but then I get Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1. I just need to solve the first error, but I have tried many options and I believe pyicu was an attempt at that.

Comment: Running this in the command line: `export PYICU_CFLAGS=-std=c++11:-DPYICU_VER='"2.0.3"'`  worked for me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was facing this issue on my mac when trying to install polyglot (pyicu is needed for polyglot). The following resolved this for me.

```
# Install icu
brew install icu4c

# check newest version
ls /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/

# Edit pyicu installer to work
git clone https://github.com/ovalhub/pyicu.git

# edit setup.py not to query for the version, i.e. change
# ICU_VERSION = subprocess.check_output(('icu-config', '--version')).strip()
# to whatever your version is, e.g.
# ICU_VERSION = '57.1'

# Install pyicu
env LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=-L/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib python setup.py build
env LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=-L/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib sudo python setup.py install

# Change DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH (not sure if req'd)
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/{version, e.g. 57.1}/:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

# Icu works now from python, and you can proceed with polyglot
$ python
>>> import icu
$ pip install polyglot
$ python
>>> import polyglot
```

Comment: I am trying to make an upload to Heroku, how do I follow these steps to evade the PyICU error using an Aptfile?

Answer (score 45):

I faced this issue on ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04. To fix this issue, install libicu-dev then try installing again. I did

```
$sudo apt install libicu-dev
$pip install pyicu
```

Comment: This one actually help me on my Ubuntu box!! Thank you @Mungai

Comment: @StevenYong, struggled with it and good to know it helped you too.

Answer (score 21):

for me to get it works:

1) install `icu4c` with brew:

```
brew install icu4c
brew link icu4c --force
```

2) check the version:

```
ls /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/
```

it prompts something like:
`64.2`

3) execute bellow commands with substitution of proper version from previous step (first line only integer part, second and third line with decimal part):

```
export ICU_VERSION=64
export PYICU_INCLUDES=/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/64.2/include
export PYICU_LFLAGS=-L/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/64.2/lib
```

4) finally install python package for pyicu:

```
pip install pyicu --upgrade
```

IF YOU FAIL with above (happen already to me on OS X `10.15`) you may need:

```
brew install pkg-config

export PYICU_CFLAGS=-std=c++11:-DPYICU_VER='"2.3.1"'
```

Comment: Following steps 1-4 didn't work for me. I had to install `pkg-config` and exported `PYICU_CFLAGS` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

On macOS 10.14.2 simply adding the directory containing `icu-config` to the `PATH` did the trick for me:

```
brew install icu4c
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"
pip install pyicu
```

In fact, this is suggested by `brew info icu4c`:

```
==> Caveats
icu4c is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS provides libicucore.dylib (but nothing else).

If you need to have icu4c first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find icu4c you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include"

For pkg-config to find icu4c you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Answer (score 8):

Below solution is for MAC OSX only-

try installing pyICU using brew:

> ```
> brew install icu4c
> ```

if it says that it's already installed and just need to be linked, then try this:

> ```
> brew link icu4c
> ```

This create relative symlinks in "/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/..."

Comment: Thanks, what worked for me was: `brew link --force icu4c` then install pyICU, then `brew unlink icu4c` to avoid conflicts while building software that depends on mac's lib version.

Comment: mac os 10.13.6 : "brew install icu4c" then "brew link --force icu4c" worked for me

Answer (score 7):

Following solution worked for me on OSX:

```
# Install ucu4c via Brew
brew install icu4c

# Create relative symlinks for icu4c
brew link --force icu4c

# Install pyicu via pip
# Make sure ICU_VERSION matches the one you just installed
sudo ICU_VERSION=60.2 pip install pyicu
```

Comment: +1 this actually works in Sierra for me as well. Even force linking with brew didn't work - explicitly telling which version to choose did! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the current version of `icu4c` packaged for `brew` does not link the `icu-config` file properly.

Running `brew link icu4c --force` gives you the necessary information to address this, but fails to link it automatically.

```
$ brew link --force icu4c
Warning: Refusing to link macOS-provided software: icu4c
If you need to have icu4c first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find icu4c you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include"

For pkg-config to find icu4c you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/pkgconfig"
```

You need to run the following after installing `icu4c` through `brew` to get `icu-config` into your path (assuming you're running bash as your shell):

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

After that, you should be able to install `pyicu` without any additional environment variables:

```
$ pip install --no-cache-dir pyicu
Collecting pyicu
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/15/0af20b540c828943b6ffea5677c86e908dcac108813b522adebb75c827c1/PyICU-2.2.tar.gz (211kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 215kB 4.9MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pyicu
  Running setup.py install for pyicu ... done
Successfully installed pyicu-2.2
```

In summary, here's a complete list of commands i ran to make this work:

```
brew install icu4c
brew link icu4c --force
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
pip install --no-cache-dir pyicu
```

(As an aside, many of the solutions i came across do not use the `--no-cache-dir` option with `pip install`. I think some of them may have cached built version of `pyicu`. I did for a while, which masked the issue. It wasn't until i tried this option that i was able to reproduce and fix appropriately.)

Answer (score 1):

This fails because `icu4c` is a keg-only formula as you can see in the Caveats section of `brew info icu4c`.

Some other answer recommend to use `brew link icu4c` but that may **cause other issues** as macOS already provides `libicucore.dylib`.

`pip install pyicu` fails because

- will try run `icu-config` command, so `icu-config` must be in the PATH
- will try to run `pkgconfig ... icu-i18n` so the `.pc` files for icu4c must be in the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`

For macOS if you don't want to `brew link icu4c` and just want to make icu4c available to your `pip install` command then you can do this instead:

```
brew install pkg-config icu4c

# brew info icu4c 
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/pkgconfig"

icu-config --version # 68.2
pkg-config --modversion icu-i18n # 68.2

pip install pyicu==2.6.0 # works because icu-config in PATH and pkgconfig can find icu4c
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install in RHEL and I installed from the tar.gz file.
Below are the commands:

```
    /usr/local/bin/pip3 install -U setuptools
    /usr/local/bin/pip3 install -U wheel
    wget http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/50.1.2/icu4c-50_1_2-src.tgz
    tar -zxvf icu4c-50_1_2-src.tgz
    cd icu
    cd source
    sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr
    sudo make
    sudo make install
    icu-config --version
    /usr/local/bin/pip3 install PyICU==2.0.6
```