# Tokenizing mutliple language text in python

Tags: python, ubuntu, tokenize, icu

I am trying to tokenize text. For it to work, I was trying [Polygot](https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation.html) and installed the way, has been mentioned in the documentation. After installing it, I have been trying to make the simple script run:

```
import polyglot
from polyglot.text import Text, Word

text = Text("\"သမၼတဦးဝင္းျမင့္ရဲ႕ ျခင္းခတ္ကစားဟန္\"\n\nႏိုင္ငံေတာ္သမၼတ ဦးဝင္းျမင့္  ျမန္မာ့ရိုးရာဝိုင္းျခင္းခတ္ ေနတဲ့ပုံေတြ ဟာ ဒီကေန႕ ညေနပိုင္းမွာထြက္ရိွလာပါတယ္။\n\nဒီကေန႕ ညေနပိုင္းမွာ သမၼတအိမ္ေတာ္ဝင္းအတြင္းမွာ သမၼတဟာ သူရဲ႕မိတ္ေဆြေတြနဲ႕ ျခင္းခတ္ခဲ့တာလို႕ သိရပါတယ္။\n\nသမၼတနဲ႕ဝိုင္းျခင္းခတ္တဲ့သူေတြထဲမွာေတာ့ အမ်ိဳးသားလႊတ္ေတာ္ကိုယ္စားလွယ္ ဦးေက်ာ္သီဟ ၊ အစိုးရ ရဲ႕ၿငိမ္းခ်မး္ေရးေကာ္မရွင္အဖြဲ႕ဝင္ ဦးေအာင္စိုးတို႕ပါဝင္ၾကပါတယ္။\n\nသမၼတ ဦးဝင္းျမင့္ဟာ   သမၼတတာဝန္မထမ္းေဆာင္မီ လႊတ္ေတာ္ကိုယ္စားလွယ္အျဖစ္ ေနျပည္ေတာ္က စည္ပင္ဧည္႕ရိပ္သာဝင္းအတြင္း ေနထိုင္စဥ္ကတည္းက အမ်ိဳးသားဒီမိုကေရစီအဖြဲ႕ခ်ဳပ္ ပါတီဝင္လႊတ္ေတာ္ကိုယ္စားလွယ္အခ်ိဳ႕နဲ႕ ညေနပိုင္းေတြမွာ  ျခင္းခတ္ေလ့ရိွပါတယ္။\n\nကိုယ္လက္လႈပ္ရွားအားကစားအျဖစ္  ျခင္းခတ္ေလ့ရိွတဲ့သူေတြထဲမွာ ေတာ့ လက္ရိွ မႏၱေလးတိုင္းဝန္ႀကီးခ်ဳပ္ ေဒါက္တာေဇာ္ျမင့္ေမာင္ ၊ ဧရာဝတီတိုင္းဝန္ႀကီးခ်ဳပ္ေဟာင္း မန္းေဂ်ာ္နီတို႕လည္း ပါဝင္ေလ့ရိွပါတယ္။ ")

print(text.words)
```

but have been getting an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "tkn.py", line 2, in <module>
from polyglot.text import Text, Word
File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/polyglot/text.py", line 9, in <module>
from polyglot.detect import Detector, Language
File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/polyglot/detect/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .base import Detector, Language
File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/polyglot/detect/base.py", line 11, in <module>
from icu import Locale

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'icu'
```

To resolve this, I tried multiple steps mentioned [here](https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot/issues/10) and few [answers as given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40940188/error-installing-pip-pyicu) but it has not solved the problem. I am working with `Ubuntu`.

Also, if I try to install `pip install pyicu` as some of the posts suggest, I get an error while trying to install it saying `Failed building wheel for pyicu` and `error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`.

I am not sure how to proceed from here. How could I resolve the related error and make the script work?

I also downloaded and installed [icu](http://site.icu-project.org/download/63#TOC-ICU4C-Download) (building it manually for Ubuntu)but no help.

```
curl -LO http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/63.1/icu4c-63_1-src.tgz
tar xzvf icu4c-63_1-src.tgz
cd icu/source
chmod +x runConfigureICU configure install-sh
./runConfigureICU Linux
make
sudo make install
sudo cp -r common/unicode /usr/local/include/
```

Comment: Do you have libicu-dev installed? Do `sudo apt search libicu-dev` to check.

Comment: @thelogicalkoan yes

Comment: Could you try some of the steps mentioned here: https://github.com/stan-dev/pystan/issues/395 - this is not the same problem, but targets the gcc one for a different package but in anaconda. Let me know if it helps.