# An error occurred while installing pyicu==2.8

Tags: python, heroku, pipenv, pyicu

I have built an API server with python's Flask package. I'm trying to deploy the server on Heroku using the terminal but doesn't seem to work. I have already tried using the [Heroku Build Pack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt)  to install packages listed in the `Aptfile` with contents:

```
libicu-dev
pkg-config
python3-icu
python3-setuptools
```

I also added the and [Python Build Pack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python) in the Heroku Web Dashboard. During the installation of `Apt Packages` here's the output I get with the `Heroku Build Pack`:

```sh
Using buildpacks:
remote:        1. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt.git
remote:        2. heroku/python
remote: -----> Apt app detected
remote: -----> Detected Aptfile or Stack changes, flushing cache
remote: -----> Updating apt caches
remote:        Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
remote:        Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
remote:        Get:3 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease [86.6 kB]
remote:        Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
remote:        Get:5 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg/main amd64 Packages [356 kB]
remote:        Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [1,232 kB]
remote:        Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [809 kB]
remote:        Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,689 kB]
remote:        Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1,098 kB]
remote:        Fetched 5,499 kB in 1s (4,812 kB/s)
remote:        Reading package lists...
remote: -----> Fetching .debs for libicu-dev
remote:        Reading package lists...
remote:        Building dependency tree...
remote:        0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
remote:        Need to get 9,450 kB of archives.
remote:        After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
remote:        Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libicu-dev amd64 66.1-2ubuntu2 [9,450 kB]
remote:        Fetched 9,450 kB in 1s (10.4 MB/s)
remote:        Download complete and in download only mode
remote: -----> Fetching .debs for pkg-config
remote:        Reading package lists...
remote:        Building dependency tree...
remote:        0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
remote:        Need to get 45.5 kB of archives.
remote:        After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
remote:        Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 pkg-config amd64 0.29.1-0ubuntu4 [45.5 kB]
remote:        Fetched 45.5 kB in 0s (152 kB/s)
remote:        Download complete and in download only mode
remote: -----> Fetching .debs for python3-icu
remote:        Reading package lists...
remote:        Building dependency tree...
remote:        The following NEW packages will be installed:
remote:          python3-icu
remote:        0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove, and 10 not upgraded.
remote:        Need to get 250 kB of archives.
remote:        After this operation, 1,192 kB of additional disk space will be used.
remote:        Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 python3-icu amd64 2.4.2-0ubuntu3 [250 kB]
remote:        Fetched 250 kB in 0s (536 kB/s)
remote:        Download complete and in download only mode
remote: -----> Fetching .debs for python3-setuptools
remote:        Reading package lists...
remote:        Building dependency tree...
remote:        The following additional packages will be installed:
remote:          python3-pkg-resources
remote:        Suggested packages:
remote:          python-setuptools-doc
remote:        The following NEW packages will be installed:
remote:          python3-pkg-resources python3-setuptools
remote:        0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
remote:        Need to get 460 kB of archives.
remote:        After this operation, 2,047 kB of additional disk space will be used.
remote:        Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 python3-pkg-resources all 45.2.0-1 [130 kB]
remote:        Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 python3-setuptools all 45.2.0-1 [330 kB]
remote:        Fetched 460 kB in 1s (766 kB/s)
remote:        Download complete and in download only mode
remote: -----> Installing libicu-dev_66.1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing pkg-config_0.29.1-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing python3-icu_2.4.2-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing python3-pkg-resources_45.2.0-1_all.deb
remote: -----> Installing python3-setuptools_45.2.0-1_all.deb
remote: -----> Writing profile script
remote: -----> Rewrite package-config files
remote: -----> Python app detected
```

Then after the `Heroku build pack` is completed, it moves to the `Heroku/python` build pack which yields the following error:

```sh
remote:          Building wheel for bson (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for bson (setup.py): finished with status 'done
remote:          Created wheel for bson: filename=bson-0.5.10-py3-none-any.whl size=11978 sha256=8054d8bcbad113bbcb2159a90f609f2a909681bcd86728e66024f3db3ef152a1
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-jp_7t95d/wheels/6d/8b/5e/68619cb02962978c6cc8eaf68ca23ef28c69de7e086740702b
remote:          Building wheel for polyglot (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for polyglot (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for polyglot: filename=polyglot-16.7.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=52578 sha256=3982ad5fdef94946e58411dfaf4ace3ffe6c310d06ad4a0f389cdc7e0d9e6171
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-jp_7t95d/wheels/77/4a/9d/5141018da475375d91dc1af07520b1f2b077579f2f55353afb
remote:          Building wheel for pycld2 (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for pycld2 (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for pycld2: filename=pycld2-0.41-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl size=9916711 sha256=6f6f7c55d43eabcc9e07778b2279716ba665cef107b4b54f3a40c66a3e72d992
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-jp_7t95d/wheels/ed/98/60/230df7a9368a02bf62e0e2719a31615b2aa82238dea526b637
remote:          Building wheel for PyICU (pyproject.toml): started
remote:          Building wheel for PyICU (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
remote:          ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
remote:           command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpjcmht5hw
remote:               cwd: /tmp/pip-install-t0elezrk/pyicu_dd2f596030aa4a418ae49a28c726d303
remote:          Complete output (90 lines):
remote:          (running 'icu-config --version')
remote:          (running 'pkg-config --modversion icu-i18n')
remote:          
remote:          Building PyICU 2.8 for ICU 66.1 (max ICU major version supported: 70)
remote:          
remote:          (running 'icu-config --cxxflags --cppflags')
remote:          Could not configure CFLAGS with icu-config
remote:          (running 'pkg-config --cflags icu-i18n')
remote:          (running 'icu-config --ldflags')
remote:          Could not configure LFLAGS with icu-config
remote:          (running 'pkg-config --libs icu-i18n')
remote:          Adding LFLAGS="-licui18n -licuuc -licudata" from /tmp/build_7569cab5/.apt/usr/bin/pkg-config
remote:          running bdist_wheel
remote:          running build
remote:          running build_py
remote:          creating build
remote:          creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
remote:          copying PyICU.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
remote:          creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/icu
remote:          copying icu/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/icu
remote:          running build_ext
remote:          building '_icu' extension
remote:          creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9
remote:          gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.9 -c _icu.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/_icu.o -DPYICU_VER="2.8" -DPYICU_ICU_MAX_VER="70"
remote:          In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/clocale:42,
remote:                           from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/c++locale.h:41,
remote:                           from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/localefwd.h:40,
remote:                           from /usr/include/c++/9/string:43,
remote:                           from /tmp/build_7569cab5/.apt/usr/include/unicode/std_string.h:37,
remote:                           from /tmp/build_7569cab5/.apt/usr/include/unicode/unistr.h:38,
remote:                           from common.h:107,
remote:                           from _icu.cpp:27:
remote:          ./locale.h:29:23: error: ‘Locale’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘locale_t’?
remote:             29 | PyObject *wrap_Locale(Locale *locale, int flags);
remote:                |                       ^~~~~~
remote:                |                       locale_t
remote:          ./locale.h:29:31: error: ‘locale’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘locale_t’?
remote:             29 | PyObject *wrap_Locale(Locale *locale, int flags);
remote:                |                               ^~~~~~
remote:                |                               locale_t
remote:          ./locale.h:29:39: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
remote:             29 | PyObject *wrap_Locale(Locale *locale, int flags);
remote:                |                                       ^~~
remote:          ./locale.h:29:48: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
remote:             29 | PyObject *wrap_Locale(Locale *locale, int flags);
remote:                |                                                ^
remote:          ./locale.h:30:29: error: ‘Locale’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘locale_t’?
remote:             30 | PyObject *wrap_Locale(const Locale &locale);
remote:                |                             ^~~~~~
remote:                |                             locale_t
remote:          ./locale.h:30:43: error: ‘PyObject* wrap_Locale(const int&)’ redeclared as different kind of entity
remote:             30 | PyObject *wrap_Locale(const Locale &locale);
remote:                |                                           ^
remote:          ./locale.h:29:11: note: previous declaration ‘PyObject* wrap_Locale’
remote:             29 | PyObject *wrap_Locale(Locale *locale, int flags);
remote:                |           ^~~~~~~~~~~
remote:          In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/c++locale.h:41,
remote:                           from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/localefwd.h:40,
remote:                           from /usr/include/c++/9/string:43,
remote:                           from /tmp/build_7569cab5/.apt/usr/include/unicode/std_string.h:37,
remote:                           from /tmp/build_7569cab5/.apt/usr/include/unicode/unistr.h:38,
remote:                           from common.h:107,
remote:                           from _icu.cpp:27:
remote:          /usr/include/c++/9/clocale:53:11: error: ‘::lconv’ has not been declared
remote:             53 |   using ::lconv;
remote:                |           ^~~~~
remote:          /usr/include/c++/9/clocale:54:11: error: ‘::setlocale’ has not been declared
remote:             54 |   using ::setlocale;
remote:                |           ^~~~~~~~~
remote:          /usr/include/c++/9/clocale:55:11: error: ‘::localeconv’ has not been declared
remote:             55 |   using ::localeconv;
remote:                |           ^~~~~~~~~~
remote:          In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/localefwd.h:40,
remote:                           from /usr/include/c++/9/string:43,
remote:                           from /tmp/build_7569cab5/.apt/usr/include/unicode/std_string.h:37,
remote:                           from /tmp/build_7569cab5/.apt/usr/include/unicode/unistr.h:38,
remote:                           from common.h:107,
remote:                           from _icu.cpp:27:
remote:          /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/c++locale.h:52:23: error: ‘uselocale’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘u_fsetlocale’?
remote:             52 |   extern "C" __typeof(uselocale) __uselocale;
remote:                |                       ^~~~~~~~~
remote:                |                       u_fsetlocale
remote:          /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/c++locale.h: In function ‘int std::__convert_from_v(__locale_struct* const&, char*, int, const char*, ...)’:
remote:          /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/c++locale.h:75:53: error: ‘__gnu_cxx::__uselocale’ cannot be used as a function
remote:             75 |     __c_locale __old = __gnu_cxx::__uselocale(__cloc);
remote:                |                                                     ^
remote:          /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/c++locale.h:100:33: error: ‘__gnu_cxx::__uselocale’ cannot be used as a function
remote:            100 |     __gnu_cxx::__uselocale(__old);
remote:                |                                 ^
remote:          error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
remote:          ----------------------------------------
remote:          ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyICU
remote:          Building wheel for readtime (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for readtime (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for readtime: filename=readtime-1.1.1-py3-none-any.whl size=7213 sha256=7ca10c74cedd95431d6dea606d72d580e4736608d1dcf844c390015b3db1b221
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-jp_7t95d/wheels/7b/28/2e/aefdfce15ec824db8570b271b2d1069b7f402c054873a74337
remote:        Successfully built bson polyglot pycld2 readtime
remote:        Failed to build PyICU
remote:        ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyICU, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to pacific-ridge-08688.
remote:
```

Perhaps I might be missing one simple thing. I would appreciate any kind assistance.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe it needs to update `pip` or `setuptools`  or `wheel`

Comment: server uses `python-3.9.9` - did you test `pyicu` on local computer with `Python 3.9` ? Maybe this module is not ready for `Python 3.9`.

Comment: `pyicu` is wrapper on C/C++ library [ICU](https://icu.unicode.org/) - maybe first you have to install library `ICU`. Or maybe it need compiler C/C++ and package with headers `.h` (usually in package with suffing `-dev` like `icu-dev`) to compiler some C/C++ code.

Comment: see also [python - Error installing pip pyicu - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40940188/error-installing-pip-pyicu)

Comment: "I have no idea how to disable `Pipenv`"—Heroku is using Pipenv because you tell it to by including a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`. If you wish to use `pip` instead, move your dependencies to a file called `requirements.txt` and delete the Pipenv files.

Comment: @furas I have tested it locally on `Python 3.9` it installs well with `Pipenv`

Comment: did you tested it on fresh system? `pipenv` check only Python modules but it can't check `C/C++` libraries (which you may have installed on local system but not on server - like `libicu`, `libicu-dev`).

Comment: @furas Yes, I did delete the project on Heroku and created a new one, but still experience the same issues. As for `libicu` it prints out `remote: E: Unable to locate package libicu` perhaps the module has been removed or discontinued..

Comment: @Chris thank you for your suggestion on deleting `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` to use `pip`. It has switched to `pip` on push, and gives a more detailed error which is updated on the question.